# Change Owner of the Script in a Site

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote some script in a site. The script makes a new spreadsheet and sends a mail to logon user. I changed the owner of the site to an other account and made me just an editor.But It seems that the script ran by my account and many spreadsheets came out in my doc list and many emails were sent from my address.
Why did the owner of the script not change, though the owner of the site was changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [the chapter in documentation on his subject](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts?hl=fr-FR#understandingPermissions) ? It has changed recently and a few options are available.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.I can deploy scripts when I login as my account, but cannot select deploy menu when I login as another acount which is the owner of the site. I have 2 project in the site. I can deploy one which I need it executed as login user, but cannot deploy another script which I need it executed as owner.

Comment: I added a new script and copied a code from the original project when I login as the site owner account. And I can select deploy as web app.